# kubectl get last restart time of a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

as a preparation I'll tell what I know

When I run `kubectl logs --previous <pod_name>` I'll get last 20lines of logs before restart and timestamp when than happened, but I wanted to have that timestamp displayed when I run `kubectl get pods` as an additional column.

The kube docs on how to create custom columns show that

```sh
kubectl get pods <my_pod_name -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,RSRC:.metadata.resourceVersion
NAME           RSRC
submit-queue   610995
```

but my question is where is this metadata/spec stored??? where can I list all possible metadata so I know what column to search or write, and same for spec and any other possible column

I know I can look at the pod with `kubectl describe pod <pod>` but how do I translate fields there to this `.metadata.name` format ?

Part of my descirbe looks like so

```sh
MacBook-Pro% kubectl describe pod xxx
Name:         xxx
Namespace:    xx
Priority:     0
Node:         myname/myip
Start Time:   Tue, 23 Feb 2021 11:37:01 +0100
Labels:       app=xx
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=xx
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              app.kubernetes.io/name=xx
              env=xx
              helm.sh/chart=xx
              pod-template-hash=yy
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2020-10-23T11:21:09+02:00
Status:       Running
IP:           10.xx
IPs:
  IP:           10.xx
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/xxx
Containers:
  my_app:
    Container ID:   docker://xxxx
    Image:          gcr.ioxxxx
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://gcrxxx
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 12 Mar 2021 11:34:42 +0100
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    143
      Started:      Fri, 05 Mar 2021 12:34:58 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 12 Mar 2021 11:34:41 +0100
```

any thought how to get to `Last State.Finished` field ?

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: That's a lot of questions staggered around, can you edit and organize it a bit?

Comment: first part was preparation, you can Ignore it I guess, the main part is in the second to last line

Comment: It seems like in k8s 1.22 it's been taken care of and `last restart` is available in `kubectl get pods -o wide` results. Here is the [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/100142) to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `kubectl get pod -o yaml` to view your POD resource in the YAML format (or `-o json` if you prefer).

In this format, you can see the `metadata` keys and values. e.g.:

```
$ kubectl get po -o yaml my-nginx-5b56ccd65f-4vmms | head -n 5
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-03-09T15:19:38Z"
  generateName: my-nginx-5b56ccd65f-
```

You can also use `kubectl explain pod` to list and describe all possible fields associated with the pod API resource. It's possible to get the documentation of a specific field of a resource (e.g., `kubectl explain pods.status.containerStatuses`).

---

To get the `Last State.Finished` value you can use:

```
$ kubectl get pods my-nginx-5b56ccd65f-4vmms -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,FINISHED:.status.containerStatuses[*].lastState.terminated.finishedAt
NAME                        FINISHED
my-nginx-5b56ccd65f-4vmms   2021-03-09T15:35:45Z
```

Comment: the only minus of that solution is that it only shows last state if it exists, so if i have 10pods, 3 restarted 7 not, so command simply wont run on pods that didnt restart; I guess solution would be to get pods that restarted and their name - and then pipe that to this command

Comment: You can use `kubectl get pods` without specifying any pods. Pods that not restarted will have `<none>` as the FINISHED value.  You can `grep -v` them out. For example: `kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,FINISHED:.status.containerStatuses[*].lastState.terminated.finishedAt | grep -v none`

Comment: yup great idea, also I'm leaving this note for any future people with similar issue as me, if you dont use bash but zsh, and are left with `zsh: no matches found: custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,FINISHED:.status.containerStatuses[*].lastState.terminated.finishedAt` simply put the text after `custom-columns=` in quotes "" and it will work

Comment: What timezone does it use?